# Получение url страницы с которой отправлена форма

Tags: php, javascript, html, url

Есть форма:

```
<div id="inline" class = "section-34 ">
<div class = "section-bottom-15">
<p class = "text-ubold my-text-big">Псевдо текст </p>
</div>
<form id="contact" action="#" method="post" name="contact">
<input id="name" class="txt" name="name" type="name" placeholder="Ваше имя" />
 <input id="phone" class="txt" name="phone" type="phone" placeholder="Ваш телефон" />
<div class = "text-ubold">
 <button id="send" onclick="ga ('send', 'event', 'submint', 'send_button'); yaCounterXXXXXX.reachGoal('buttonClick'); return true;">Задать вопрос</button>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

Есть обработчик:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function validateEmail(email) { 
    var reg = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return reg.test(email);
  }

   jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery("#contact").submit(function() { return false; });
        jQuery("#send").on("click", function(){
            var emailval = jQuery("#email").val();
            var namevl  = jQuery("#name").val();
            var namep = namevl.length;
            var phonevl  = jQuery("#phone").val();
            var ph  = phonevl.length;         

    if(namevl  == false) {
                jQuery("#name").addClass("error");
            }
            else if(namevl == true){
                jQuery("#name").removeClass("error");
            }

            if(phonevl == false) {
                jQuery("#phone").addClass("error");
            }
            else if(phonevl == true){
                jQuery("#phone").removeClass("error");
            }

               if(namep > 1 && ph > 1) {
                jQuery("#send").replaceWith("<em>отправка...</em>");
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/sendmessage.php',
                    data: jQuery("#contact").serialize(),
                    success: function(data) {
                        if(data == "true") {
                            jQuery("#contact").fadeOut("fast", function(){
    yaCounterXXXXXX.reachGoal('sendForm');
    ga ('send', 'event', 'submit', 'sendform');
                                jQuery(this).before("<p><strong>Ваша заявка принята! Ожидайте.</strong></p>");
                                setTimeout(1000);
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Есть PHP скрипт, который формирует и отправляет сообщения:

```
<?php
$sendto   = "mail@mail.ru"; // Обязательно измените e-mail на свой
$usermail = $_POST['email'];
$username = $_POST['name'];
$userphone = $_POST['phone'];
$content  = nl2br($_POST['msg']);
// Формирование заголовка письма
$subject  = "Важно!!! Возможно клиент!";
$headers  = "From: " . strip_tags($usermail) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($usermail) . "\r\n";


$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8 \r\n";
// Формирование тела письма
$msg  = "<html><body style='font-family:Arial,sans-serif;'>";
$msg .= "<h2 style='font-weight:bold;border-bottom:1px dotted #ccc;'>Новое сообщение</h2>\r\n";
$msg .= "<p><strong>Имя:</strong> ".$username."</p>\r\n";
$msg .= "<p><strong>Номер телефона:</strong> ".$userphone."</p>\r\n";
$msg .= "<p><strong>Посетитель с сайта, у него возникли вопросы, надо ему позвонить</strong> ".$usermail."</p>\r\n";
$msg .= "<p><strong></strong> ".$content."</p>\r\n";
$msg .= "</body></html>";

// отправка сообщения
if(@mail($sendto, $subject, $msg, $headers)) {
    echo "true";
} else {
    echo "false";
}

?>
```

Kак в письме получить url страницы с которой отправлена форма?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

поскольку данные добавляются аяксом, то ссылку на страницу придется добавить в `hidden` поле формы. Можете либо в саму форму ее впихать, если она генерится каждый раз на странице, если же форма статична и кэшируется к примеру,  то добавить поле при отправке формы.

```
jQuery('<input>').attr('type','hidden')
          .attr('name', 'ref')
          .val(location.href)
          .appendTo("#contact");

jQuery.ajax(...)
```

на стороне пхп получить в

```
$referer = $_POST['ref'];
```

Comment: в общем это как вариант решения с явной передачей страницы. в целом в некоторых случаях реферер может обрезаться, + можно явно прописывать какие нить до опции а-ля вкладок на странице.

Comment: Большое спасибо, все работает) Очень помогли)

Answer (score 3):

```
parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], PHP_URL_HOST)
```

Ссылка на доку - [ссылка](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php.)

Comment: вы что там ожидаете увидеть для аякса? тем более страница нужна а не хост.

Comment: @teran то же, что и без аякса — страницу, с которой отправлен запрос?

Comment: @andreymal емнип, пусто там будет для аякс запроса, хотя могу и ошибаться конечно

Comment: @teran не будет. Там может быть пусто или только хост, если в настройках браузера реферер отключен (поэтому ваш ответ лучше), а так при отправке запросов со страниц он обычно содержит таки ссылку на страницу

Comment: @andreymal похоже ваша правда.

Comment: @Valera - HTTP_REFERER это уже давно "не точная наука", многие браузеры (современные) начали не поддерживать данную возможность и часто не отправляют данные, и не важно у пользователя включена возможность или нет...

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать *document.referrer*. Он хранит URL, с которого пришли на страницу

Comment: на сервере не существует обьект document.