# Получить url страницы с которой отправлена форма

Tags: php, html, url

Есть форма

```
    <div class = "offset-sm-top-15 offset-lg-top-15 offset-md-top-15 offset-xl-top-15"><a href="#" id="callback" class="send-popup text-uppercase" onclick="ga ('send', 'event', 'submint', 'popUpButton'); yaCounterXXXXXX.reachGoal('popUpClick'); return true;">Предварительный заказ</a></div>

     <div id="popup">
        <form id="contact_form" role="form" method="post" action="/order.php">
            <p class = "text-white text-small">Текст</p>
            <input type="text" name="name"  placeholder="Как к вам обращаться?" autofocus>
            <input type="text" name="tel"  class="required" placeholder="Текст>
    <div class = "section-15">        
    <a href="#" class="btn button form_submit" onclick="ga ('send', 'event', 'submint', 'sendPopUp'); yaCounterХХХХХХ.reachGoal('popUpSend'); return true;">Отправить</a>
    </div>
     </form>
    </div>
```

Есть PHP скрипт, формирующий письмо

```
    <?php
        header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
        error_reporting(0);   

    if(!empty($_POST['send'])) {

        $name = substr(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['name'])), 0, 300);
        $tel = substr(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['tel'])), 0, 100);

        $mess  = "Имя: <b>".$name."</b><br />";
        $mess .= "Телефон: <b>".$tel."</b><br />";

        $theme = "Заявка с сайта";

        mail("mail@mail.ru", $theme, $mess, "From: mail.ru <mail@mail.ru>\nContent-Type: text/html;\n charset=utf-8\nX-Priority: 0");

        echo "<h3 style = 'color: white'>Заявка удачно оформлена.</h3>";
        echo "<p style = 'color: white'>Наш менеджер свяжется с вами в ближайшее время.</p>";

        }
    else {
        echo "<h2>Ошибка! Попробуйте еще раз.</h2>";
    }
    ?>
```

Как получить url страницы с которой отправлена форма?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Получение url страницы с которой отправлена форма](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/768488/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-url-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b-%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0)

Comment: Если я правильно понял, у вас одна и та же форма находится на разных страница и вы хотите знать откуда данные прилетели ?

Comment: Да, все верно, форма подключается на страницу через include

Comment: @Arsen Да, все верно, форма подключается на страницу через          <!--#include virtual="">